# Using the Facebook API to post to live stream plugin? (not to a user or page's wall)

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm working on creating a Facebook application that re-creates a live stream and I'm having trouble with permissions. Originally the 'stream' was going to the application's wall, but a user cannot post onto an application's wall without liking the page first (and therefor granting publish permissions to that app's wall).

Our current solution is a Facebook social plug-in - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/live-stream/ - which works fine but we're not able to customize it. Does anyone know of a way using the Facebook API to post to a live stream object? Ideally I'd like to re-create the social stream by hand using a combination of the FQL to fetch new posts made in the stream and using their API to create new posts for the stream. Any leads would be fantastic.